# Looking for simple flex component for audio playback

Tags: apache-flex, audio

I want to add a simple audio control (play/pause/seek/volume) control to my flex application. Please suggest some free , preferably open source component.

Answer (score 2):

You could always just use the Sound class. You can see an example of this at http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/articles/54989.aspx